# Leftover text is left in the input field when addFromAutocompleteOnly is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I am using the ng-tags tags-input like this:

```
<tags-input ng-model="Tags" placeholder="Add" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
    <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

I want any leftover text to disappear when the tags-input field loses control. I wanted to use the allowLeftoverText attribute to achieve this but the documentation says its ignored when the addFromAutocompleteOnly is used.

Comment: add fiddle or plunkr please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any text left in the input element will remain there until the user removes it herself. The `allowLeftoverText` function is to mark the element as invalid when there is some leftover text so you can show some error message to the user.

And that option isn't ignored when `addFromAutocompleteOnly` is true. The documentation was outdated, but it has been fixed already.

Version 3.0 introduced a way to change the input value programmatically. This is how leftover text can be accessed (Note- ng-blur would remove the leftover text):

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" text="textVar" ng-blur="textVar=''"></tags-input>
```

Comment: Thx, I'll keep an eye out for version 3.0. I did indeed misunderstand the allowLeftoverText. I thought it would remove leftover text.

Comment: @Michael Can you please illustrate how left over text can be removed? I tried `on-invalid-tag` but that is not triggered for left over text

Comment: @ShyamalParikh You can access the leftover text by using the `text` option. If you set it as an empty string then the input will be cleared.

Comment: @MichaelBenford Thanks, actually I only edited the answer but since I didn't have high reputation JoJoe approved it instead. :)

Comment: @MichaelBenford, finally implemented this. Works like a charm :)

Comment: @MichaelBenford Only if I could mark it useful 100 times!